# Cloning via GitHub CLI returns usage error

Tags: github

I am trying to clone a repository using `gh repo clone` command as it is also shown on the Github repo page [image: Github repo clone]

`gh repo clone https://github.com/xardox69/android_EPG`
but it is giving error:

> usage: gh [-h] [--home] [-p] [-b] [-s] [-r] [-t] [-c] [-w] [-i] [-d] [-v]
> gh: error: unrecognized arguments: repo clone https://github.com/xardox69/android_EPG

Comment: What does `gh --version` print?

Comment: gh version: v0.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The version of gh that you're using is quite old and doesn't implement this feature.  The easiest thing to do here is just clone the repository using Git over HTTPS or SSH.  If you're not sure which one to use, HTTPS typically doesn't require authentication unless you're pushing and will be easier to set up in most cases.

You can also try to figure out where you got gh from and upgrade it to a newer version.  How to do that depends on how you installed it and what OS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

use sudo apt install gh for installing gh then do gh auth login